OpenMP target error `alias definitions not supported in this configuration`
I want to use OpenMP target construct to run a loop on a GPU device. After many trial, I discovered that my gcc compiler fails to compile a recursive function.
After many trials, I isolated my problem in this small test.c function:
int func(int par){
 if(par<0) return par;
 return func(par--);
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 100;
      #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for 
      for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
          func(i);
  }
}

This is the way I  compile it
gcc-12  -foffload=nvptx-none -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -foffload=-misa=sm_35  -fopenmp test.c -o testcpp.exe

This is the error I get:
test.c:5:5: error: alias definitions not supported in this configuration
    5 | int func(int par){
      |     ^
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-12 returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The error disappears if I do not call func recursively.
Note: I am aware that this test case is useless, however, consider that this is just a small example to reproduce the behaviour I have in a more complicated set-up.
How to reproduce the issue: I set up this small google-colab notebook where you can reproduce the issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zHVwKBt1hrkrDvw5IxqPwxovpC8gkVwA
My question is: how can I compile a kernel with recursion using OpenMP target construct?

Not all GPUs support recursion and when they do, it is often not efficient (in fact, it is often not efficient on CPU too). For example, Nvidia supports it on device targetting at least compute capability 2.0 and CUDA 3.1 (that is pretty old Nvidia GPUs and early CUDA versions). Not to mention recursive calls tends to have a varying depth resulting in warp divergence issue (and thus very bad performance on GPUs). Can't you rewrite the implementation so to avoid recursion and warp divergence?

For valid OpenMP code, you would need to add a declare target directive for a function that should be executed from a target region. But, to answer your question: gcc-14 on Ubuntu 24.04 compiles your code with just a relocation warning.

@JérômeRichard  I need recursion for parallel tree build. nVIDIA technical blog  parallel tree build uses recursion so I guess this is the beast we can get for this problem https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/
